# Why do I have numbers in my username when I logged in to SEDE?

Tags: bug, data-explorer, display-names, unicode

Today I logged in at https://data.stackexchange.com/ using my Stack Overflow account. I got surprised when I found numbers in my username in the top bar.

My username is `Cédric`, but when I logged in, it appears as `C233dric`.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It seems that it replaces the `é` with the Unicode decimal code `&#233`.

Until it gets fixed, you can go to your profile and edit your display name to replace the code with the corresponding character.

Comment: 233 = 0xE9. [U+00E9. é. UTF-8 0xC3 0xA9. LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=233)