# Tags with certain special characters don't display correctly in search results

Tags: bug, status-review, tags, search, unicode

On [Spanish Language Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com) we have an [[españa] tag](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espa%c3%b1a). It is correctly displayed in the list of questions tagged [españa]:

[image: tag search]

but not when [searching for keywords](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=descifrar), where it shows as [espa#a]:

[image: search using keywords]

The [link to the tag](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espa%23a) also leads to nowhere.

Another example is [[vocabulario-técnico]](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%c3%a9cnico) where the 'é' gets dropped entirely: [vocabulario-tcnico].

Comment: Possibly related ("[é](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89)" in that case, an [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) one, like [ó](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%93) mentioned in the answer): *[Why do I have numbers in my username when I logged in to SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382593/)*

Comment: Summary of the issue (mostly so I can copy/paste it when I send it to the devs): Certain special characters in tag names are not displaying properly on search results pages (on any site where there are such tag names); this also affects the URLs the tag names link to. Affected characters: `é` and `à` (they vanish entirely – causing the [à] tag on French to disappear completely in search results), `ç` (it becomes `+`), and `ñ` (it becomes `#`). Unaffected: `á`, `ã`, `â`, `ê`, `í`, `ó`, `õ`, `ô`, `ú`, `ü`.

Answer (score 4):

The `ó` [seems to be working](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bidentificaci%C3%B3n-de-t%C3%A9rmino%5D+dice+en+jerga+t%C3%A9cnica+cuando). I just tested searches with the same diacritics on [Portuguese Language Stack Exchange](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com) and they seem to be working. However, on [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) the [`ç` C-cedilha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87) is currently [showing the same problem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Borienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos%5D+Quando+estudei+MVC).

[image]

Comment: ...Looking at the first link in your answer, it looks like there are issues with tags containing some special characters even there. The first tag displays correctly as `selección-de-palabras` below the search result. However, the other 3 tags are displayed as `solicitud-de-trmino`, `vocabulario-tcnico`, and `identificación-de-trmino` – it looks like the `é` character isn't being displayed there at all (and the links are similarly broken as a result).

Comment: Those tags *should* be getting displayed as `solicitud-de-término`, `vocabulario-técnico`, and `identificación-de-término` (and if you click on the question, they do appear properly there). So it looks like it's only affecting the search results, not the question pages themselves. And I guess it might only be affecting some special characters but not others...

Comment: Continuing to test: It looks like `ú`, `í`, and `ü` are displaying fine as well, per [this search](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo+se+puede+contar+desde+el+fin+de+una+serie%3F). And so is `á`; [see here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=Es+com%C3%BAn+omitir). So far, it looks like `é` is vanishing entirely, `ç` is being turned into `+`, and `ñ` is being turned into `#`.

Comment: @V2Blast I gave this some thought, and the problem is likely that the enconding isn't Unicode atm (somewhere in some layer)... If we look at the [U0080 table](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) all those chars are in the same range (unless SE uses combining characters, I don't know about that).